# Python подсвечивает = как invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я столкнулась с проблемой, что когда я писала программу для разлиновки листа по координатам, Python не понял, что я хотела объявить переменную.Я, пока что только учусь писать код, так что не судите строго

P.S- Если что версия 3-X

Вот сам код:

```
def write_lines(a, b, divider):
    clean_count = a - b
    frequent = clean_count/divider
    for i in range(0,divider):
        return decision = a + frequet*i
print(write_lines(3.0, 8.83, 3))


  return decision = a + frequet*i
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Что, по-вашему, должна делать строка `return decision = 0 + frequet*i`?

Comment: как минимум у вас в return `frequet` а определили ее как `frequent`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как справедливо замечено в комментариях, в вашем коде встречаются сразу ряд ошибки.

1. инструкция возврата значения из функции `return` возвращает результат указанного выражения и сразу же выходит из функции. Поэтому присвоение в инструкции `return` бессмысленны. Вам нужно изменить строку следующим образом:

```py
# заменить это
return decision = a + frequet*i

# на это 
return a + frequent * i
```

2. Ну и тут же следующая ошибка - это опечатка. Вы определяете переменную `frequent`, а далее по тексту кода уже используете переменную `frequet`.
3. Не совсем ясен смысл того, что вы хотите сделать в цикле. Как я уже писал в пункте 1 - `return` сразу же выполняет выход из функции. В вашем случае `return` сработает на первой же итерации, вернет полученный результат от `i = 0`, после чего выйдет из функции. Если вы хотели вернуть все расчеты цикла, то, судя по всему, вам нужно создать список результатов и возвращать его.

В итоге ваш код , скорее всего, должен выглядеть как-то вот так:

```py
def write_lines(a, b, divider):
    clean_count = a - b
    frequent = clean_count/divider
    res = [a + frequent * i for i in range(0,divider)]
    return res

print(write_lines(3.0, 8.83, 3))
```

Comment: Хотела бы дать вам что-то типо апвоута, но не знаю как.

Answer (score 0):

В Python так нельзя делать, по крайней мере в текущей версии. Но можно так (отдельно присваивание, отдельно возврат).

```
decision = a + frequent*i
return decision
```

Хотя непонятно, зачем вам цикл, если вы из него тут же выходите.